# hg log not finding file even though it exists

Tags: command-line, mercurial, tortoisehg

**I am not understanding why Mercurial sometimes cannot find file when it does a log command, but it always finds it when I do a status.**

For example:

`hg status --change "1111" "path\to\file"` -- Returns path to file

`hg log -r "1111" "path\to\file"` -- Returns changeset

**But, sometimes it fails with a different changeset:**

`hg status --change "2222" "path\to\file"` -- Returns path to file

`hg log -r "2222" "path\to\file"` -- Returns nothing

How can this be? If the file exists proven through the use of a status command, how can I not retrieve the changeset through log on some changesets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hidden in the documentation it seems like this solved my issue:

> For performance reasons, 'hg log FILE' may omit duplicate changes made
>   on branches and will not show removals or mode changes. To see all
>   such changes, use the --removed switch.

Seems a little ridiculous that you have to specify this, especially when you already explicitly state the file.